# How to lock DB files from C# so that 3rd party softwares can't access them

Tags: c#, locking

My requirement is 
"Locking of our database files is done in such a way that all actions taken from within our application process are allowed, only third party application/service access is blocked." In order to ensure that third party software does not lock any of our database files after our application is running, we should explicitly lock all database files to prevent that.

Background:
I am working on a desktop application and sql ce as database and N-hibernate. Some times when ever our app isrunning 3rd party softwares such as backup softwares which will run frequently and do a system backup at that time it will lock our db files.

so my requirement on launch of my app i should lock my db files in such a way that any thread or any action with in my application should perfrom all operations on database but 3rd party operations should be restricted.

I tried with sample by FileLock but this is failing with in my app when performing some db operation through N-hibernated. Please help me on this is this really acheivable if so please let me know.

Comment: I would feel that trying to second-guess what 3rd party software will or won't do and at what time is not the best way to approach this; in your scenario, if the user is letting his backup software run whilst using your app, and he has included the app's database file in his backup plan, then he kind of expects that database to be included as well, no? If you inform the user up front "you can't backup the database whilst running this app" then that's clear to them and it's not an unusual thing, either.

Comment: I agree with Stephen here: better to change what is accessing the db than to try to lock from your application. For example what if your application hangs and needs to be restarted? Will it be able to get the exclusive lock on startup or will you be stuck with the old one hanging on? What happens if some reporting tool or even a new version in dev wants to connect to the production database? Probably easiest to put the database in a folder that is excluded from backup or AV or whatever is getting the locks at the moment. Have a maintenance window or have your app itself handle backups.

Answer (score 0):

Using `File.Open` for write operations without disposing it will generally keep the lock on the file. Others will not be able to write, however they can still read it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new account/user. Overwrite the file permission to only this user. and impersonate your application to this newly created user. as a result other user can not use your file.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know since when SQLCE started supporting desktop application. I prefer using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) . It natively supports locking of database file, using sqlite provider only. Check that out. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Apparently SQLCE has supported desktop applications at least since the SQL Server 2005 version. The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417(v=sql.90).aspx) is unclear on it being a new feature, however.